# How to prepend/append content to event cells in FullCalendar v5?

Tags: fullcalendar

In [Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) v5 I am looking to prepend/append a button to each cell where events are shown.

In v5 this appears to be done through the [content injection hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection) here, however these examples like this one:

```
eventContent: function(arg) {
  let italicEl = document.createElement('i')

  if (arg.event.extendedProps.isUrgent) {
    italicEl.innerHTML = 'urgent event'
  } else {
    italicEl.innerHTML = 'normal event'
  }

  let arrayOfDomNodes = [ italicEl ]
  return { domNodes: arrayOfDomNodes }
}
```

Completely replace the cell including the events, I want to keep the events as they are and just add a HTML button before/after them.

I have console logged the args in the [eventContent event render function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks), but cannot see how I would do this?

I previously did this using [dayRender in v4](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/dayRender), but this appears to have been replaced in v5 with these new hooks.

I have also tried the [eventDidMount](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection), this adds a button but as this is done on every event, if there are multiple within the cell you get multiple buttons.

```
    eventDidMount: function(event) {

        console.log(event);
        $(event.el).closest('td[role="gridcell"]').find('.fc-daygrid-day-top').prepend('<button class="button button-secondary button-small">Add</button>');
        $(event.el).closest('td[role="gridcell"]').find('.fc-daygrid-day-top').append('<button class="button button-secondary button-small">Add</button>');

    },
```

Comment: You don't need to put an "add" button into the cells. If you want users to be able to add an event on a particular day/time slot, just handle the "select" callback in fullCalendar - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting

Comment: @ADyson I wish to use buttons over selecting the day using the method you mention to give a visual indication of how to add an event. With selectable: true, if you have a lot of dragable events in a cell it can be difficult to understand you need to click outside the events already in there to add one.

Comment: `to give a visual indication of how to add an event.`...if users can't figure it out (which most can), you could always just put some text on your page somewhere nearby saying "click or drag an empty space on the calendar to create an event". Much simpler. And makes the calendar a lot less busy and messy than all those buttons (which there might not be much room for if there are already several events on the day)

Comment: P.s. not sure why you're using the event content injection for this task anyway? That will add per event, as you've discovered. On the comments you asked me the other day, I already linked you to the day cell content hooks.